# Picture Not Being Uploaded

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have been trying to upload a picture in RoR but the picture is not being uploaded.
Code snippet for my controller is

```
def employee_params_with_pic
    params.require(:employee).permit( :phone, :personal_email, :address, :picture)
  end
```

The code in my view to upload the image is

```
<div>
    <%= f.label :Display %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture %>
</div>
```

When I select the picture to be uploaded,the following result is
[image: The filename of the picture]

The null field of database is removed. Instead it shows no values
[image: no values]

The picture does not appear in the field where it was supposed to show.

The view to display the image is

```
<span class="content">
    <%= image_tag @employee.details.url if @employee.picture? %>
</span>
```

Comment: What is the field type of your picture column? Are you using any gem to upload image?

Comment: I am using the following gems
gem 'carrierwave',             '1.1.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '4.7.0'
gem 'fog-aws',                 '2.0.0'
gem 'nokogiri',                '1.8.1'

Comment: what is the data type of `picture` column?

Comment: the data type is string

Comment: did you add `mount_uploader` in `Employee` model for `picture` field?

Comment: Yes, I have
mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

Comment: @L11  i think it should be `@employee.picture_url` `in image_tag`?

Comment: can you share the whole form here??

Comment: <%= form_for(@employee, url: employee_update_url(:id => @employee.id), method: :patch) do |f| %>
                <div class="c">
                    <div class="grid formgroup">
                        <div>
                            <%= f.label :id %>
                                :</div>
                          <div>
                            <%= f.label :Display %>
                        <%= f.file_field :picture %>
                        </div>
Omitted the rest because it's too long

Comment: Try adding html: {:multipart => true} to the form

Comment: please clarify the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be something this :

```
<%= image_tag @employee.picture_url if @employee.picture? %>
```

Comment: not working...
my database doesn't show any values, not even null

Comment: are you using `aws` bucket for storing it local ?

Comment: using **fog-aws** gem is being used

Comment: check in `mount_uploader` if your wats your `storage type`?

Comment: mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

Comment: check on rails console if `@employee.picture_url` what does it return?

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `picture_url' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):1

Comment: have you added any validation in `employee` model?

Comment: except picture all field are being saved?